# Message Routing, Partitioning and Parallel Processing

Tags: c#, .net, f#, set-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem with partitioning and parallelization on a set of incoming messages. I want to partition based on user id which is an integer.

So assuming I have a hundred thousand users and I want X execution threads or partitions, I want to be able to create X threads with partitioning rules like userid < 10000, userid > 100000 < 50000 etc. and be able to validate that these partitions cover the entire set of users and that there are no duplicates (i.e. there is no intersection between the sets represented by each of the partitioning rules).

How can I implement an algorithm to validate the partitioning rules in C# (or any .NET language like F#)?

So if i have 10 users with id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) the total of the threads must have only 10 user ids with no duplicate user id in more than 1 thread

Thanks for the responses so far but I want to clarify that I'm not looking at partitioning evenly among all existing users. Rather I want to be able to create a partitioning rules table that defines how the partitioning should be done. The table might look something like this:

```
Thread 1: UserId > 0 < 100
Thread 2: UserId >= 100 < 200
Thread 3: UserId > 300
```

What I want is an algorithm that can validate that these set of rules are exhaustive (cover all user ids) and contain no duplicates (no user id will be allocated to more than one thread)

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` and `Parallel.For` already partition the input data. The partitioning can handle both [fixed *and* dynamic sizes, and use load balancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl) - ie if one partition ends up with a lot of "heavy" processing, the rest of the data can go to other worker tasks.

Comment: What is your *actual* question? `How can I implement an algorithm to validate the partitioning rules` should be easy - partition the data and check that the contents of each partition don't violate the rules. If the question is how to ensure the threads get the correct partitions, what threads? You haven't explained how the data will be processed. Using Parallel.ForEach? PLINQ? Your own code? Something else?

Comment: Are you trying to *route* messages to different workers with different priority? That's not partitioning.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you're right. This includes prioritization and message routing. I might have bungled the terminology. I've edited the title to add a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to realize such a partitioning logic would be to partition by modulo division.
I.e. if you have n partitions to distribute your user to - simply do a modulo division of the UserId by n. That will give you a rest of 0..(n-1) and by that rest every UserId is automatically mapped to one of your n partitions (threads).

If the UserIds are evenly distributed, this partitioning scheme will even also be statistically evenly distribute all users over the existing partitions.

And this distribution scheme is per definition exhaustive because there can be only a rest of 0..(n-1) for such a modulo division and every UserId has a defined result for such a modulo division.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will partition a list of messages into groups depending on how many messages you have and how many groups you want.

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Message>> GetPartitionedMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages, int nPartitions)
{
    var orderedMessages = messages.OrderBy(x => x.UserId).ThenBy(x => x.MessageId).ToList();
    int? lastUserId = null;
    int maxPartitionSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(orderedMessages.Count / (double)nPartitions);
    var partitions = new List<List<Message>>();
    List<Message> currentPartition = null;

    foreach (var message in orderedMessages)
    {
        if (lastUserId == message.UserId)
        {
            currentPartition.Add(message);
        }
        else
        {
            lastUserId = message.UserId;
            if (currentPartition == null || currentPartition.Count >= maxPartitionSize)
            {
                currentPartition = new List<Message>();
                partitions.Add(currentPartition);
            }

            currentPartition.Add(message);
        }
    }

    return partitions;
}
```

This example app uses the function and then does a mock process function on each message. Each group (i.e. the list that will be processed by each thread) will never contain a user ID from another list. The example app prints to the console a message containing which thread is processing which message and what the ID and user ID of each message is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User IDs 1, 2, 3");
            ProcessMessages(GetTestMessages(1, 2, 3), 4);

            Console.WriteLine("User IDs empty");
            ProcessMessages(GetTestMessages(), 4);

            Console.WriteLine("User IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10");
            ProcessMessages(GetTestMessages(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 4);

            Console.WriteLine("User IDs 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10");
            ProcessMessages(GetTestMessages(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 4);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Message> GetTestMessages(params int[] userIds)
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var userId in userIds)
                yield return new Message { MessageId = i++, UserId = userId };
        }

        private class Message
        {
            public int MessageId { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            //... Real message properties
        }

        private static void ProcessMessages(IEnumerable<Message> incomingMessages, int nThreads)
        {
            var tasks = GetPartitionedMessages(incomingMessages, nThreads)
                         .Select((messages, i) => Task.Run(() => DoMessageBusinessLogic(messages, i)))
                         .ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }

        private static void DoMessageBusinessLogic(IEnumerable<Message> messages, int threadIdx)
        {
            foreach (var message in messages)
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID: {threadIdx}, MsgId: {message.MessageId}, UserId: {message.UserId}");
        }

        private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Message>> GetPartitionedMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages, int nPartitions)
        {
            var orderedMessages = messages.OrderBy(x => x.UserId).ThenBy(x => x.MessageId).ToList();
            int? lastUserId = null;
            int maxPartitionSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(orderedMessages.Count / (double)nPartitions);
            var partitions = new List<List<Message>>();
            List<Message> currentPartition = null;

            foreach (var message in orderedMessages)
            {
                if (lastUserId == message.UserId)
                {
                    currentPartition.Add(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastUserId = message.UserId;
                    if (currentPartition == null || currentPartition.Count >= maxPartitionSize)
                    {
                        currentPartition = new List<Message>();
                        partitions.Add(currentPartition);
                    }

                    currentPartition.Add(message);
                }
            }

            return partitions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like what op is asking is different. The question seems to be 'how do I validate my partitioning rules'